# How to add multiple source files to the test executable in googletest without redefinition errors

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am new to googletest and CMake. I wanted to learn googletest so I decided to try writing and running some tests on a collection of files I wrote a while back.

My directory looks like:

```
-CMakeLists.txt
-normTest1.cpp
-deathTest1.cpp
-normTest2.cpp
-deathTest2.cpp
-build
  -[all CMake files like Makefile, cache, bin, lib, etc.]

-my_library_dir
  -obj1.h
  -obj2.h
  -obj1.cpp
  -obj2.cpp
  -my_library.h
```

Now my CMakeList.txt is: (based on this tutorial: https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my-library-testing)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CXX_FLAGS "${${PROJECT_NAME}_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929.zip
)

# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  library_test
  normTest1.cpp
  normTest2.cpp
  deathTest1.cpp
  deathTest2.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
  library_test
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(library_test)
```

and each of my `.*Test[12].cpp` files have an `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` and a `#include "my_library_dir/my_library.h"` in them.

Unfortunately, executing `cmake -S . -B build` and then `cmake --build build` gives me a bunch of linker errors because of multiple definitions of functions in the source files of `my_libary_dir` across each `*.o` file. How can I edit my CMakeLists.txt file to get around these linker errors? Temporarily, I am only putting one source file in the `add_executable(...)` and instead `#include`ing the other source files in the one source file that I include in `add_executable`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot solve this on a cmake level... There seems to be something wrong with the `my_library.h` header. The offending symbols should be pretty easy to identify given the linker output, but basically impossible without sources and output. Btw: The preferred cmake way of setting the standard would be `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS Off)` or `set_target_properties(library_test PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17 CXX_EXTENSIONS Off)`

Comment: As previous commenter said, the problem is most likely about your test files and/or your header file. So we cannot help you without viewing these file and the exact error message you got. Please, add all that information into the question post.